How long would it have taken to travel from Southampton to Madeira by boat in the 1920s?
I’d like to know how long it would have taken to travel to Madeira by boat in the 1920s. I have archive material of my Father being seen off from Southampton docks on this journey. I assume it would have been a steamer stopping off at Funchal on its way to Africa and/or India?

Documenting preliminary research will improve both the probability of an answer and the quality of the answer(s). At a minimum, all questions should explain why Wikipedia is insufficient.

This list of the Royal Mail Service to Cape Town/South Africa before 1914 gives four days for Southampton–Madeira.
The line was served by the Union-Castle Line, 1911 sold to the Royal Mail Line, but continued to operate under its own name. After the end of WWI, the line aquired two new steamers, the RMS Arundel Castle and the RMS Windsor Castle. Both had two steam turbines at a total of 15,000 HP and a service speed of 17 knots.
The distance from Southhampton to Madeira is around 1300 nautical miles. At 17 knots, that would be a travel time of 76.5 hours, plus the time spent at slower speeds to get out of the Solent and through the Channel. At least in clement weather a three-day run, as described by a contemporary might have been possible.

(+1) Sources from the 1920s state that Madeira was an intermediate stop on the route from Southampton to Cape Town, and that the Union-Castle liners left Southampton once a week.

G. Aston, Memories of a Marine. London: John Murray 1919, p. 261: "Voyages in the South African mail-steamers are very much alike and vary only with the changes
of passengers and companionship. A description of one covers them all: the partings from friends at Southampton and the start at about half-past four; [...] Then there is the three-day run to Madeira, with, according to the weather, about half the passengers visible, the remainder having disappeared into their..."

@njuffa I think I spot the deciding factor: This page lists a "service speed" of 17 kn for the Arundel, while in all other sources it seemed to be implied to be the maximum speed. If the two ships could indeed maintain that speed for the whole journey, three days might be doable, at least in good weather.

I think "good weather" is the operative phrase. Companies offering regularly scheduled long-distance service on the high seas presumably included some buffering. So the Southampton-Madeira leg may have been 3 to 4 days depending on weather. FWIW, the entire trip from Southampton to Cape Town took about sixteen days. Which means that there must have been more than two ships servicing this route in order to achieve weekly service.

@njuffa, yes, there was for example also the Walmer Castle, but all sources point out the two I named were the largest and fastest on the route until 1930, when they were refit with stronger motors.

@njuffa sorry, I quoted the wrong year. The refit happened in 1937 and apparently was the result of a new mail contract which required a minimum speed of 19 kn. That is mentioned in the WP article about the 1926 built Carnarvon Castle.

Also, for a departure in late afternoon or evening, my experience (sample size of 3, all 3 times) is that the trip length is counted by "days at sea - excluding nights at sea". Thus a 96 hour travel time, leaving in late afternoon and arriving the morning of the fourth day, counts as a "3 day" journey.
